# Can't quit my WP7 silverlight app

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I use this method to close my app:

```
public void quit()
{
    if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
    {
        while (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null)
        {
            NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
        }
    }
}
```

When I call it after pressing back key, the app closes as intended:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    quit();
}
```

But anywhere else I call this method, the stack is emptied but the app will not close.

If I try:

```
quit();
NavigationService.GoBack();
```

There will be a runtime error. If anybody can help me because I don't like to through an exception since it will be recorded as a bug in the marketplace statistics.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to clear the Navigation stack; if the application terminates the navigation stack will be gone. Do not worry about the user going forward; there is no forward key.

To remove the exception:

```
quit();
if( NavigationService.CanGoBack)
{
    NavigationService.GoBack(); 
}
```

But before you do this, look at the code: what are you trying to accomplish? First you are cleaning out the stack and then you want to use the stack.

Comment: Thanks for your notes. I don't know why it eventually worked when I called 'NavigationService.GoBack()' before 'quit()' not after it.